# How to write this query in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-4

I search the net but I could not find the solution to my problem,
I am a Codeigniter developer and now I started a project in Laravel

my query in Codeigniter Active record is like this:

```
public function show_brt($id = 0,$tax_cat_id,$lang="en") 
{
    $records = $this->db
            ->select('
                t1.id,
                t1.date_received, 
                t1.customer_name, 
                t1.memo, 
                t1.percent_tax_withheld, 
                t1.gross_invoice_amount, 
                t1.tax_amount_withheld, 
                t1.net_amount_received, 
                t1.tax_payment_date, 
                t2.rate, 
                t3.name_' . $lang. ' AS deposit_account'
                )
            ->from('brt AS t1')
            ->join('exchange_rate AS t2', 't2.id = t1.exchange_rate_id','left')
            ->join('balance_sheet_accounts AS t3', 't3.id = t1.deposit_account_id','left')
            ->where('t1.income_statement_account_id', $id)
            ->where('t1.tax_cat_id',$tax_cat_id)
            ->where('t1.company_id', $this->session->userdata('company_id'))
            ->where('t1.fiscal_year_id', $this->session->userdata('fiscal_year_id'))
            ->where('t1.user_id', $this->m_auth->get_user_id())
            ->get();

    if ($records->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $records;
    }
}
```

could any one help me that how can I write like this queries which should be safe from sql injections in Laravel Eloquent or Fluent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code: I'm basically from CI. I have done one migration. It may not best solution. I didn't test.

```
DB::table('brt AS t1')
     ->select('t1.id,
                t1.date_received, 
                t1.customer_name, 
                t1.memo, 
                t1.percent_tax_withheld, 
                t1.gross_invoice_amount, 
                t1.tax_amount_withheld, 
                t1.net_amount_received, 
                t1.tax_payment_date, 
                t2.rate, 
                t3.name_' . $lang. ' AS deposit_account'
            )
     ->leftjoin('exchange_rate AS t2', 't2.id', '=', 't1.exchange_rate_id')
     ->leftjoin('balance_sheet_accounts AS t3', 't3.id', '=', 't1.deposit_account_id')
     ->where('t1.income_statement_account_id', '=',$id)
     ->where('t1.income_statement_account_id','=', $id)
     ->where('t1.tax_cat_id','=',$tax_cat_id)
     ->where('t1.company_id','=', $this->session->userdata('company_id'))
     ->where('t1.fiscal_year_id','=', $this->session->userdata('fiscal_year_id'))
     ->where('t1.user_id','=', $this->m_auth->get_user_id())
     ->get();
```